# How to use Window Manager in Android

Tags: java, android, screen

I want to prevent screen locking while my app is running. I have used Power Manager which consumes more battery life. I want to use Window Manager for this. How to use Window Manager for all the activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great new year ahead. wishes for 2014. raise point and answer if feasible to you.

Hi did you tried with this

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

or

```
KeyguardLock.disableKeyguard()
```

Comment: Happy New year to you too. i have directly put this code in activity. It shows error. Can you specifically told me where to put these code.

Comment: write this code in your oncreate getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

Comment: It works. Thanks. Should i need to write it on each activity or in just Main Activity.

Comment: if it works please raise my points :)hehe..it depends on yours logic how you use it